# Boundary regularity of solutions to semilinear heat equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, parabolic-pde

Consider the Cauchy IVP problem 
$$u_t - \Delta u + f(t,x,u) = 0, \quad (t,x) \in (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}^n,$$
with initial condition $u(0,x) = g(x), \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n.$

Can you point out a reference to a theorem to the effect that, under reasonable assumptions on $f$ and $g$, the unique solution $u$ to the problem is regular up to the time $t=0$ and therefore $u(0,\cdot)$ solves the equation?